# How to get the latest URL of my blog?

Tags: posts, urls, blog

How to get the latest URL of my blog?

Meaning, if I want to create a **dynamic URL** which will automatically redirect to my **latest** (*max id*) post?

Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

easy to do with `get_posts`

```
    // search the last post
    $posts = get_posts([
        "posts_per_page" => 1,
    ]);


    foreach ($posts as $p) {
        // display the permalink
        echo esc_html(get_permalink($p));
    }
```

documentation of `get_posts` :
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts